# Auto Generated SKU

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

When I activate Auto Generated SKU's in Craft Commerce, I get the "SKU's cannot be left blank" error when I submit a new product. Isn't it the point to leave them blank so they'll auto generate based on other fields?

Comment: What is your `Automatic SKU Format` setting set to?

Comment: I just kept it simple to see how it worked. {product.slug}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little awkward, but the documentation has a note about this: https://craftcommerce.com/docs/product-types#automatic-sku-format

If a product does *not* have a variant, then you'd just use `{slug}`.  If it *does* have a variant, then you'd use `{product.slug}`.  This should be less awkward in the upcoming Commerce 2 as well.

Comment: Brad, would there be a way to include an asset field to help in the auto-generation of SKUs? I'd like to have a product image filename be the SKU number. I've tried {productImage.filename} and {product.productImage.filename} and came up empty.

Comment: Assets are always in array format.  So if you wanted the first Asset, you'd use `{productImage[0].filename}` or `{product.productImage[0].filename}` depending on the variant situation.

Comment: Worked wonderfully! Except I didn't realize the file extension was included in filename. Any way to avoid the file extension in the SKU?

Comment: I can't get this to work for variants... I have the variant SKU set to `{product.slug}` and the automatic SKU format for the product type set to the same... but it isn't being translated into anything on the front end.

Comment: Yes just to add that @BradBell's method does not work for variant products. By setting the value to `{product.title}` the SKU field does not show for any variants, and saving failed because you cant enter a unique SKU. This unfortunately makes commerce near unusable for products with large numbers of variants - you cant expect clients to sit manually entering hundreds of SKU codes that could just auto increment.